# Wordpress AJAX call returns undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

** Have edited with more detail, thanks for your help so far

I am trying to create an AJAX search on my Wordpress website to filter properties by type, location and status.

I am new to AJAX and have been following some guides to get to where I am now but am stuck on the last part. It seems to all be working but when I loop through my AJAX call using a `for` loop it returns `undefined`

Code from JS file

```
$ = jQuery;

var bedSearch = $("#prop-search");

var searchForm = bedSearch.find("form");

searchForm.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        action : "prop_search",
        status : bedSearch.find("#status").val(),
        location_of_accom : bedSearch.find("#location").val(),
        propertytype : bedSearch.find("#property_type").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url : ajax_url,
        data : data,
        success : function(response) {


            bedSearch.find("ul").empty();

            for(var i = 0; i < response.length ; i++) {
                console.log(response[i]);
            }

        }
    });

});
```

The code for the AJAX callback ( in functions.php ) :

```
// create ajax callback

add_action ('wp_ajax_prop_search', 'bed_search_callback');
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_bed_search', 'bed_search_callback');

function bed_search_callback() {

    $status1=0;
    if(isset($_GET['status'])) $status = $_GET["status"];

    $location_of_accom = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['location_of_accom'])) $location_of_accom = $_GET["location_of_accom"];

    $propertytype = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['propertytype'])) $propertytype = $_GET["propertytype"];

    $result = array();

    $args = array(
        "post_type" => "accomodation",
        "posts_per_page" => -1
    );



    $args['meta_query'][] = array (
        'key' => 'status',
        'value' => $status,
        'compare' => "LIKE"
    );

    $args['meta_query'][] = array (
        'key' => 'location_of_accom',
        'value' => $location_of_accom,
        'compare' => "LIKE"
    );

    $args['meta_query'][] = array (
        'key' => 'propertytype',
        'value' => $propertytype,
        'compare' => "LIKE"
     );





     $bed_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($bed_query->have_posts() ) {

        $bed_query->the_post();

        $result[] = array(
            "id" => get_the_ID(),
            "title" => get_the_title(),
            "permalink" => get_the_permalink()
        );


}


        echo json_encode($result);

        wp_die();  
}
```

For reference : I've been following this guide which has all worked apart from the very last step where I cannot print it out like he shows. Mine prints it out 1 character at a time :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ol8aBPmjdmA

My output : [Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9DcW.png)

Comment: Could you please edit the question to show exactly what the content of `response` is

Comment: Hi Rory, please take a look at the recent edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

YOur response should be in array, object or json format in order to see it in a for loop. in php file when you return a value make sure that it has been in returned in 1 of this 3 types.

Comment: Thank for your help Elman, how would you put the response in an array?

Comment: In wordpress file where you return result you can use json_encode function to generate json object and then echo it. After that in js file response will be in json format so you can parse via Json.parse function and thats it.

Comment: @AlexHyslop if my answer helps can you tick it as a correct one please?